# need help in my add node method in my binary tree

Tags: java

I did a code about inserting nodes in a binary tree ... My code is not working because of some reasons in my add method , please look at my comments next to each line .. here is my code where I get problem with ..

```
    public class BinarySearchTree<E extends Comparable<? super E>> {
    BinaryNode<E> root;

    /**
     * Constructs an empty binary searchtree.
     */
    public BinarySearchTree() {

    }
    /**
     * Inserts the specified element in the tree if no duplicate exists.
     * @param x element to be inserted
     * @return true if the the element was inserted
     */
    public boolean add(E element) {

        BinaryNode newNode = new BinaryNode(element);

        if(root==null){
            root=newNode;
        } if (element==this.element){ // element cannot be resolved or is not a field
            return false;
        } else {

            BinaryNode<E> focus = root;
            BinaryNode parent;

            while(true) {
                parent=focus;
                if (element < focus.element) { //The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) E, Object 
                    focus=focus.left;
                    if (focus==null) {
                        parent.left=newNode;
                        return true;
                    }
                } else {
                    focus=focus.right;
                    if (focus==null) {
                        parent.right=newNode; // 
                        }
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

    }
static class BinaryNode<E> {
        E element;
        BinaryNode<E> left;
        BinaryNode<E> right;

        private BinaryNode(E element) {
            this.element = element;
        }   
    }

}
```

How to correct my errors?

Is my code suitable? Does it need to be changed?

Thank you

Comment: Unless your type `E` is a subtype of `Number` (In which case you should state that) you should not use `==` and `<` to compare. `==` compares for equality which for objects means the same object instance. For non primitive values `>` and `<` is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your code where you make a compare element less than focus.element, i have puted element.compareTo(focus.element) < 0, is the way to compare thing without being an integer

```
public class BinarySearchTree<E extends Comparable<? super E>> {
    BinaryNode<E> root;

    /**
     * Constructs an empty binary searchtree.
     */
    public BinarySearchTree() {

    }
    /**
     * Inserts the specified element in the tree if no duplicate exists.
     * @param element to be inserted
     * @return true if the the element was inserted
     */
    public boolean add(E element) {

        BinaryNode newNode = new BinaryNode(element);

        if(root==null){
            root=newNode;
            System.out.println("root");
        } if (element==root.element){ // element cannot be resolved or is not a field
            return false;
        } else {

            BinaryNode<E> focus = root;
            BinaryNode parent;

            while(true) {
                parent=focus;
                if (element.compareTo(focus.element) < 0) { //Here is my change!!! The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) E, Object
                    focus=focus.left;
                    System.out.println("left");
                    if (focus==null) {
                        parent.left=newNode;
                        return true;
                    }
                } else {
                    focus=focus.right;
                    System.out.println("right");
                    if (focus==null) {
                        parent.right=newNode; //
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    static class BinaryNode<E> {
        E element;
        BinaryNode<E> left;
        BinaryNode<E> right;

        private BinaryNode(E element) {
            this.element = element;
        }
    }

}
```